# Sprite Touching Other Sprite Game Over in Java

Tags: java

```
@Override
public boolean isGameOver() {
    return player.getHealth() <= 0;
}

@Override
public void destroy() {

}

@Override
public void reset() {
    player.reset();
    enemies.clear();
    addEnemies();

    bulletHandler.reset();
}

public void addEnemies() {
    for(int y = 0; y < 5; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++){
            FishType e = new BasicFishType(150 + (x * 40), 25 + (y * 40), 1 , 3, bulletHandler);
            enemies.add(e);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean isComplete() {
    return enemies.isEmpty();
}
```

}

As of right now, this is my level code. It has a state which allows it to play. There is also a Game Over Screen. However the Invaders slowly speed up the longer they are on the screen for. the problem is, the invaders can just get to the bottom of the screen and then that's it. I don't die and the invaders are no longer on the screen. I'm just wondering, how do i make it so that when the player sprite touches the invader sprite it results in an automatic game-over.

```
@Override
public boolean deathScene() {
    if(!enemySprite.isPlay())
        return false;

    if(enemySprite.isSpriteAnimDestroyed()) {
        if (!explosionSound.isPlaying()) {
            explosionSound.play();
        }
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean collide(int i, ThePlayer player, BlockyBlocks blocks, ArrayList<FishType> enemys) {
    if(enemySprite.isPlay()) {
        if(enemys.get(i).deathScene()) {
            enemys.remove(i);
        }
        return false;
    }

    for(int w = 0; w < player.playerWeapons.weapons.size(); w++) {
        if(enemys != null && player.playerWeapons.weapons.get(w).collisionRect(((BasicFishType) enemys.get(i)).getRect())) {
            enemySprite.resetLimit();
            enemySprite.setAnimationSpeed(120);
            enemySprite.setPlay(true, true);
            GameScreen.SCORE += 8;
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isOutOfBounds() {
    if(rect.x > 0 && rect.x < Sea_InvadersDisplay.WIDTH - rect.width)
        return false;
    return true;
```

EDIT: Removed the sounds from the code, as really the main problem is with the lives and touching sprites. Is there is a way to either:
1. Cause Gameover once sprites go off the bottom of the screen
2. Cause gameover by setting lives to 0 if playerSprite touches Invadersprite
3. Cause Gameover by collision of the two sprites

Comment: You ask a question about sprites and yet we see code about sounds. Would you mind creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? So that we can entirely focus on the problem itself?

Comment: Sorry, i'm just not entirely sure on this code, there are many parts which i don't understand, so i try to get some help here and there. I have edited it, but i'm not sure if that would be enough...

Comment: You should probably change your `isGameOver` method to `return !hasPlayerLife() || anyEnemyHitsTheGround();` and then `boolean anyEnemyHitsTheGround() { for (Enemy e: ...) { if (e.getY() == GROUND) { return true; } } return false; }`.

Comment: I'll give that a gander, and see how it handles.